# How to assign button in XIB Interface Builder in Xcode 6 for a Mac app

Tags: xcode, macos, interface-builder, xcode6, xib

I am making an attempt at my first Mac app. I have a bit of experience with Objective-C and iOS game apps, but have never used an XIB file or Interface Builder before.

I have created a MasterViewController class with XIB and can successfully get this XIB to show from the AppDelegate by using the following:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

    self.masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.window.contentView addSubview:self.masterViewController.view];
    self.masterViewController.view.frame = ((NSView*)self.window.contentView).bounds;

}
```

There is a single Label and a single Button on the screen, but I cannot figure out how to connect Button so that it fires an action when it is clicked.

Here is the MasterViewController.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface MasterViewController : NSViewController

-(IBAction)testMessage;
-(IBAction)testAction;

@end
```

Here is the MasterViewController.m

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"

@interface MasterViewController ()

@end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(IBAction)testMessage {
    NSLog(@"testMessage");
}

-(IBAction)testAction {
    NSLog(@"testAction");
}
```

Here is screenshot of Interface Builder:

[image: XIB]

When I look at the File's Owner section, my testAction does not appear in the list and I can therefore not drag to associate.

I am sure I am just missing something simple, but how do I assign MyButton1 click to my testMessage action?

I am using Xcode 6.1.1 on OSX 10.9.5

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your IBAction to trigger it has to be like the following:

```
- (IBAction)testAction:(id)sender {}
```

You're missing the **(id)sender** part.

If this doesn't work I have a few more solutions.

Comment: Awesome! I knew it was something simple. When I add the sender part, then testAction now appears in the XIB File's Owner section and I can then drag from it to the button to connect them.